# How to Decompress content from http response using .NET Core 3.1 using TcpClient and SslStream?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having a problem and i'm not using `HttpClient` because i'm having a problem about invalid headers that cannot be read after `PostAsync()` invoked.

My solution for that, was to implement the automation using `TcpClient` with `SslStream`. This way works well but when I get a response that I have to decompress de content returned, I'm not getting solve the decompression.

The content returned is :

> \u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0�\a\u001cI�%&/m�{\u007fJ�J��t�\b�\u0013$ؐ@\u0010������\u001diG#)�*��eVe]f\u0016@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fd\u0001l��J�ɞ!���\u001f?~|\u001f?"����\a)�L\r\u0002\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0

The `httpResponse` is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552001; preload
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Public-Key-Pins: pin-sha256="base64+primary==&quot
Set-Cookie HttpOnly: Secure
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Feature-Policy: vibrate 'self'
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2023 19:51:37 GMT
Content-Length: 290
```

Can anyone help me with this???

I'm using .NET 3.1 with C# too.

I think I tried of everything that was possible.

Which is funny because the response should be a Json message result.

I tried use `GzipStream`, `DeflateStream` e `BrotliStream` to decompress the content but none of them works.

Take a look at the response headers:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

It said that the content was compressed by `gzip`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.